# Allow filenames in bash associative array

Tags: bash, files

I am using the following to fill `fdir` with directory names, whilst removing any duplicates.  Would like to allow valid filenames as well.

```
declare -A tag
for dpa in "$@"; do
  [[ ! -d $dpa ]] && continue
  [[ ${tag[comint:$dpa]} ]] && continue
  fdir+=("$dpa")
  tag[comint:$dpa]=1
done
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "allow valid filenames". Could you explain a bit more, what you want? example?

Comment: I want that if `[[ -f $dpa ]]`, I add `dpa` to `fdir`.

Comment: `[[ -f $dpa ]] && fdir+=( "$dpa" )` ?

Comment: I want the condition to behave as with directories.  For invalid files and repeated files, I do not add to `fdir`.

Comment: I want the condition to behave as with directories. For invalid files and repeated files, I do not add to `fdir`.  Currently the code fails for files when reaching `[[ ! -d $dpa ]] && continue`.

Comment: on ext4 all characters except `NULL` and `/` are allowed, so you probably want to find your own scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `[[ -d $dpa ]] || [[ -f $dpa ]] || continue` caters for files as well.

```
declare -A tag
for dpa in "$@"; do
  [[ -d $dpa ]] || [[ -f $dpa ]] || continue
  [[ ${tag[comint:$dpa]} ]] && continue
  fdir+=("$dpa")
  tag[comint:$dpa]=1
done
```

Comment: I have been thinkering about using `[[ ${tag[comint:$dpa]+X} ]] && continue`.  Would this make sense?